"Will be living since" vs "Will have been living since"
Could you tell me which is correct, please? The following is just part of an exercise given at B2 British Council online course, so no context at all.

Joe will be living in Austria since April.
Joe will have been living in Austria since April.


I feel since does not fit well with will.   "Joe will be living in Austria from next April" might be better, as might "Joe will have been living in Austria for three months by  next April" and many other variants.

Since refers back to past things. See Cambridge dictionaries page.

@Henry This is one of those cases where will have means surely has.  So "He will have been living there since April" simply means "He has surely been living there since April".  It is a statement  of probability and belief in the eyes of the speaker about something that they in the present believe about the past.

I don't get the logic of either without further context justifying the creepiness. Even "Who's on first?" at least started off explaining the new, odd names of baseball players.

Can you say where any of the previous Answers fell down, please?
